# Google analytics- differences in Metrics

Tags: google-analytics

I started google analytics a week back and I have gone through some site to understand it but I am really confused about the metrics though. Can anyone tell me the difference between ga:visitors, ga:newVisits, ga:visits and ga:pageviews with some common example.
I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ample documentation on this already... a google would have given you:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=visitor